# YoutubePlugin of ckeditor with Django

Tags: django, ckeditor

Acutually I'm working on a Django website and I used CKEditor to input the rich text which worked well.

But when I tried to add the youtube plugin into the default setting of ckeditor, there is always an 404 error said can't find the js file. Don't know it's the setting fault or what.

I followed https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor#installation to install ckeditor. And downloaded YoutubePlugin from https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/youtube. I unzip the youtube folder into /myproject/staticfiles/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins.

Here is my settings.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles/'
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'skin': 'moonocolor',
        'toolbar_Basic': [
            ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
        ],
        'toolbar_YourCustomToolbarConfig': [
            {'name': 'document', 'items': ['Source']},
            {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Undo', 'Redo']},
            {'name': 'editing', 'items': ['Find', 'Replace']},
            {'name': 'basicstyles',
             'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
            {'name': 'paragraph',
             'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', '-',
                       'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'insert',
             'items': ['Image', 'Flash', 'Youtube', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule']},
            {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
            {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
        ],
        'tabSpaces': 4,
        'height': 300,
        'width': '100%',
        'extraPlugins': 'youtube',
    },
}
```

And the models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True,)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')

    # The default manager
    objects = models.Manager()

    # Custom made manager
    published = PublishedManager()
    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail_view',args=[self.publish.year, self.publish.strftime('%m'), self.publish.strftime('%d'), self.slug])
```

And my file system

[image: file system]

Comment: I found the reason of 404. Because django looks for the files in /bloc/static as this is an app. I create folders as /bloc/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins and paste the youtube folder into it. And after the refresh, 404 error disappears! But in the ckeditor youtube button still wasn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly problem by myself.
For 404 error, it's because of the application static file.
Django looks the static files of an app from the static folder in the app directory. And in my /blog/static there isn't the ckeditor folder. Copy the whole ckeditor folder into /blog/static with youtube plugin in plugins folder and it's fixed.

Config now:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'skin': 'moono',
        'toolbar_Basic': [
            ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
        ],
        'toolbar_YourCustomToolbarConfig': [
            {'name': 'document', 'items': ['Source']},
            {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Undo', 'Redo']},
            {'name': 'insert',
             'items': ['Image', 'Youtube', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule']},
            {'name': 'editing', 'items': ['Find', 'Replace']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'basicstyles',
             'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
            {'name': 'paragraph',
             'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', '-',
                       'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock']},
            {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
            {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
        ],
        'toolbar': 'YourCustomToolbarConfig',  # put selected toolbar config here
        # 'toolbarGroups': [{ 'name': 'document', 'groups': [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] }],
        'height': 420,
        'width': '100%',
        # 'filebrowserWindowHeight': 725,
        # 'filebrowserWindowWidth': 940,
        # 'toolbarCanCollapse': True,
        # 'mathJaxLib': '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.2-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
        'tabSpaces': 4,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join([
            'uploadimage', # the upload image feature
            # your extra plugins here
            'youtube',
        ]),
    }
}
```